# Custom Error Messages in CITRUS Test Results

Tags: citrus-framework, citrus-engine

I want to use my custom error messages in my citrus test results.
Example:
Original Error Message: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\expectedOutput\Smaple.xml (The system cannot find the file specified).

Custom Message: Hey The File was not found in your directory Please check. (Need to print like this in my test results failure message).

Please check the image here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnSEe.png)

Comment: @Christoph Deppisch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not change this message in particular as this is coming from the thrown Java exception. You could implement your own TestReporter and/or TestListener though to translate the error into something matching your needs.

Something like: https://citrusframework.org/samples/reporting/